# Paste values from Windows clipboard in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How could I run an universal Paste-values function with VBA that would work for Pasting data from Windows clipboard? To be more precise:

I have range `A1` as a helper range and `A2` where I want to display the result. The problem with code snippet:

```
Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

This works up until I copy from Excel range, however that's not always the case. If I do a copy from another system, I get an error message:

```
PasteSpecial method of Range class failed
```

Alternative code snippet is:

```
Range("A1").Activate
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A2").Value = Range("A1").Value
```

This will utilize `A1` as the helper range so that format of Range `A2` wouldn't be ruined.

I experience a different problem here. I often copy values starting with `0` and even as I have range `A1` formatted as text, which would accept values starting with 0, regular `Paste` function overwrites that formatting and automatically clears out the 0 from the start (e.g. turning 0123 into 123).

`xlPasteValues` doesn't do that, but appears not to be compatible with non-Excel copy.

Is there a way to overcome this (retain 0 in the beginning in `A1`, but also avoid any formatting updates in `A2`)?

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do. A `DataObject` from the forms library gives VBA access to the clipboard. Perhaps you could use that. See https://excelhelphq.com/how-to-read-or-access-the-clipboard-with-excel-vba/